# How to exclude blacklisted files from ls?

Tags: bash, grep, ls

I have a `blacklist` file:

```
$ cat blacklist
Iran
Iraq
Libya
Somalia
Sudan
Syria
Yemen
```

How do I exclude the files listed in this `blacklist` file from the output of `ls`? I've read the man pages and the closest thing is the `--ignore` option  which unfortunately doesn't read a file. I also thought of piping the output of `ls` to `grep` and using the `--invert-match` option to ignore all the files in the `blacklist` file but I don't know how to do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have to use `ls`, you could do this:

```
ls | grep -vFxf blacklist
```

- `-v` to invert selection
- `-F` to treat lines from file blacklist as strings, not patterns
- `-x` to match the whole line
- `-f` to reads from blacklist for patterns / strings to match

Note that the above solution works for all cases except where file names have newlines in them.